# Typescript React type Attribute

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

While I make write code with Typescript + React, I found some error.

When I make type/value in `<a>` tag attribute, I get compile Error.

`<a value='Hello' type='button'>Search</a>`

This code get occur error

`TS2339:Property 'value' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>'.`

How can I solve this compile problem? I search few hours but I cannot get solution :(

Comment: That's right, an `a` element doesn't have a value attribute

Comment: I think you've mixed `a` with `input`, `a` has neither `value` nor `type`, whereas `input` has them both.

Comment: Ahha! Thank you for all!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because value is not a valid HTML attribute for the `<a>` element. I think the best would be to use an attribute like `<a data-value="Hello">` instead of trying to extend the `AnchorHTMLAttributes` interface.